# Unable to retain Telerik drop down lists selected value on postback

Tags: asp.net, telerik

Below is my code . I am using telerik drop down list..but what is happening is that , after selecting a value from drop down list , when the page is posted back..my selected value is getting dis appeared.

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="cmbSavedSearch" runat="server"
            AutoPostBack="true"
            AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
            EnableItemCaching="True" 
            DataSourceID="odsSavedSearch" 
            DataTextField="User_Search_Nm" 
            DataValueField="User_Search_Id"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="SavedSearchSelected"
            Width="200px"
            EnableViewState="true" 

            >
            <Items>
                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Please Select..." Value="0" />
            </Items>
        </telerik:RadComboBox> 

 protected void SavedSearchSelected(object source, EventArgs e)
      {
      try
      {
        SavedSearchId = Conversion.ToInt32Default(cmbSavedSearch.SelectedValue, 0);
        cmbSavedSearch.FindItemByValue("0").Selected = true;
        cmbSubVessel.Items.Clear();            
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        bool rethrow = 
       ExceptionPolicy.HandleException   ex,CurrentSite.Instance.Error_UI_Policy_Name);
        NameValueCollection errDetail = new NameValueCollection(1);
        errDetail.Add("UserErrorMessage", UserErrorMessage);
        ExceptionHandler handler = new ExceptionHandler(ex, errDetail);
    }
```

}

Comment: Does this combo located in UpdatePanel or ajaxyfied with telerik radajaxmanager? If so, does `odsSavedSearch` control updated on combo's postback?

Comment: @Yuriy : No..it is written straight way..in aspx page

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that you are loading your `RadComboBox` on every `PostBack`.

You should check whether the page is being loaded for the first time or if the page is posted back on the server when the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event is fired.

Here is how it should work:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (!IsPostBack)
     {
         LoadcmbSavedSearch();
     }
 }
```

If you load `Items` into your `RadComboBox` on every `Postback`, your `SelectedValue` will be lost, since your `RadComboBox` just got constructed.